# Django - unique together case insensitive

Tags: django, django-models

For Django 1.11:

It is possible to have unique together with  case insensitive ?. now is case sensitive

Ho can I override the unique_together  Validation Error ?

Comment: See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14564

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to always lowercase the data before you save it. This way you can use the regular unique validation on your model.

Comment: is not the best option because I want the values/characters to remain as where introduced, not as lowercase. For example the name of product or category. I can add a version(duplicate) of them lowercase and compare this version, but it is not the best also, because I need to add many fields lowercase to the model.